# view hexadecimal strings on python shell

Tags: python, string, hex

In Scapy, I took the first 28 Bytes of a few packets and saved each as a hexadecimal string. Whenever I want to print those strings all together (they are saved in a list), the following happens:

```
>>> print myStrings[0]
['E\x00\x00W\x00\x00@\x00\x01\x11\xe7-\x8a`t\x86\xd5\x92\xbd\xef0\x1a\xa4\xe8\x00C\xe2k', ['E\x00\x00W\x00\x00@\x00\x01\x11\xe7-\x8a`t\x86\xd5\x92\xbd\xef0\x1a\xa4\xe8\x00C\xe2k']]
```

But if I want to print each string separately:

```
>>> for p in tmpStrAns:
...     print p[0]
... 
EW@�-�`t�Ւ��0��C�k
E8@�L�`t�Ւ��0��$�L
E8@�L�`t�Ւ��0��$�L
```

(`MyStrings` is a list of lists: `[[string1, [string2,string3,...], ...]` )

What's happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When printing a list, Python calls `list.__str__`, which calls `repr` on each of its items.

When printing a string, Python outputs the string directly.

```
>>> print "\x11"
�
>>> print ["\x11"]
['\x11']
>>> print repr("\x11")
'\x11'
```

The `repr` method on strings converts non-printable characters to their hexadecimal representation.